# There is $\lambda \in F$ such that $M-\lambda I$ is not invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be an algebrically closed field and $M \in M_n(F)$ . I have to show since $F$ is algebrically closed ,there is $\lambda \in F$ such that $M-\lambda I$ is not invertible.

Comment: Do you know about the characteristic polynomial? Note that $n\ge3$ and $M$ non-scalar are redundant.

Comment: @egreg .right..

Answer (score 1):

The theory of the characteristic polynomial carries over to any field. So, for every square $n\times n$ matrix $M$, the characteristic polynomial $p_M(X)=\det(M-XI)$ has the eigenvalues of $M$ as roots and its degree is $n$.

Thus $p_M(X)$ has at least a root $\lambda$ in the algebraically closed field and, since $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, the matrix $M-\lambda I$ is not invertible.

Similarly, you can conclude that $M-\lambda I$ is invertible for infinitely many values of $\lambda$ (every algebraically closed field is infinite).

Note that $n\ge3$ and $M$ non-scalar are redundant hypotheses.

<sub>Also note that I don't consider $0\times0$ matrices: there's only one and not really important.</sub>